# ¿Como descifrar cadena de javascript contenido oculto?

Tags: javascript, codificación

En Google Chrome existe una gran variedad de extensiones para descargar vídeos de fondo o a la vez utilizar las herramientas de desarrollador y **sources** se puede visualizar las vinculaciones con el sitio web.

Pero por alguna razón existe una cadena una codificación con **javascript** que no permite poder encontrar el video, es una muy buena técnica.

En este [enlace](https://p.w3layouts.com/demos_new/30-01-2017/classic_login_form-demo_Free/395814285/web/js/jquery.vide.min.js) se puede visualizar mejor el código, y en esté [enlace](https://p.w3layouts.com/demos_new/30-01-2017/classic_login_form-demo_Free/395814285/web/index.html) se puede visualizar el vídeo de fondo.

> Me pueden explicar como se puede leer una codificación o cadena de javascript

```
!function(a,b){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],b):b("object"==typeof exports?require("jquery"):a.jQuery)}(this,function(a){"use strict";function b(a){var b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i={};for(f=a.replace(/\s*:\s*/g,":").replace(/\s*,\s*/g,",").split(","),h=0,g=f.length;g>h&&(c=f[h],-1===c.search(/^(http|https|ftp):\/\//)&&-1!==c.search(":"));h++)b=c.indexOf(":"),d=c.substring(0,b),e=c.substring(b+1),e||(e=void 0),"string"==typeof e&&(e="true"===e||("false"===e?!1:e)),"string"==typeof e&&(e=isNaN(e)?e:+e),i[d]=e;return null==d&&null==e?a:i}function c(a){a=""+a;var b,c,d,e=a.split(/\s+/),f="50%",g="50%";for(d=0,b=e.length;b>d;d++)c=e[d],"left"===c?f="0%":"right"===c?f="100%":"top"===c?g="0%":"bottom"===c?g="100%":"center"===c?0===d?f="50%":g="50%":0===d?f=c:g=c;return{x:f,y:g}}function d(b,c){var d=function(){c(this.src)};a('<img src="'+b+'.gif">').load(d),a('<img src="'+b+'.jpg">').load(d),a('<img src="'+b+'.jpeg">').load(d),a('<img src="'+b+'.png">').load(d)}function e(c,d,e){if(this.$element=a(c),"string"==typeof d&&(d=b(d)),e?"string"==typeof e&&(e=b(e)):e={},"string"==typeof d)d=d.replace(/\.\w*$/,"");else if("object"==typeof d)for(var f in d)d.hasOwnProperty(f)&&(d[f]=d[f].replace(/\.\w*$/,""));this.settings=a.extend({},g,e),this.path=d,this.init()}var f="vide",g={volume:1,playbackRate:1,muted:!0,loop:!0,autoplay:!0,position:"50% 50%",posterType:"detect",resizing:!0};e.prototype.init=function(){var b,e=this,g=c(e.settings.position),h="";e.$wrapper=a("<div>").css({position:"absolute","z-index":-1,top:0,left:0,bottom:0,right:0,overflow:"hidden","-webkit-background-size":"cover","-moz-background-size":"cover","-o-background-size":"cover","background-size":"cover","background-repeat":"no-repeat","background-position":g.x+" "+g.y}),b=e.path,"object"==typeof e.path&&(e.path.poster?b=e.path.poster:e.path.mp4?b=e.path.mp4:e.path.webm?b=e.path.webm:e.path.ogv&&(b=e.path.ogv)),"detect"===e.settings.posterType?d(b,function(a){e.$wrapper.css("background-image","url("+a+")")}):"none"!==e.settings.posterType&&e.$wrapper.css("background-image","url("+b+"."+e.settings.posterType+")"),"static"===e.$element.css("position")&&e.$element.css("position","relative"),e.$element.prepend(e.$wrapper),"object"==typeof e.path?(e.path.mp4&&(h+='<source src="'+e.path.mp4+'.mp4" type="video/mp4">'),e.path.webm&&(h+='<source src="'+e.path.webm+'.webm" type="video/webm">'),e.path.ogv&&(h+='<source src="'+e.path.ogv+'.ogv" type="video/ogv">'),e.$video=a("<video>"+h+"</video>")):e.$video=a('<video><source src="'+e.path+'.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="'+e.path+'.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="'+e.path+'.ogv" type="video/ogg"></video>'),e.$video.prop({autoplay:e.settings.autoplay,loop:e.settings.loop,volume:e.settings.volume,muted:e.settings.muted,defaultMuted:e.settings.muted,playbackRate:e.settings.playbackRate,defaultPlaybackRate:e.settings.playbackRate}).css({margin:"auto",position:"absolute","z-index":-1,top:g.y,left:g.x,"-webkit-transform":"translate(-"+g.x+", -"+g.y+")","-ms-transform":"translate(-"+g.x+", -"+g.y+")","-moz-transform":"translate(-"+g.x+", -"+g.y+")",transform:"translate(-"+g.x+", -"+g.y+")",visibility:"hidden"}).one("canplaythrough."+f,function(){e.resize()}).one("playing."+f,function(){e.$video.css("visibility","visible"),e.$wrapper.css("background-image","none")}),e.$element.on("resize."+f,function(){e.settings.resizing&&e.resize()}),e.$wrapper.append(e.$video)},e.prototype.getVideoObject=function(){return this.$video[0]},e.prototype.resize=function(){if(this.$video){var a=this.$video[0].videoHeight,b=this.$video[0].videoWidth,c=this.$wrapper.height(),d=this.$wrapper.width();this.$video.css(d/b>c/a?{width:d+2,height:"auto"}:{width:"auto",height:c+2})}},e.prototype.destroy=function(){this.$element.off(f),this.$video&&this.$video.off(f),delete a[f].lookup[this.index],this.$element.removeData(f),this.$wrapper.remove()},a[f]={lookup:[]},a.fn[f]=function(b,c){var d;return this.each(function(){d=a.data(this,f),d&&d.destroy(),d=new e(this,b,c),d.index=a[f].lookup.push(d)-1,a.data(this,f,d)}),this},a(document).ready(function(){var b=a(window);b.on("resize."+f,function(){for(var b,c=a[f].lookup.length,d=0;c>d;d++)b=a[f].lookup[d],b&&b.settings.resizing&&b.resize()}),b.on("unload."+f,function(){return!1}),a(document).find("[data-"+f+"-bg]").each(function(b,c){var d=a(c),e=d.data(f+"-options"),g=d.data(f+"-bg");d[f](g,e)})})});
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta, donde no encuentras el video, viendo el source de la pagina o usando las herramientas de desarrollador de google?. Si solo quieres obtener el video, usa las herramientas de desarrolladores de chrome ubícate en la pestaña elements, y luego busca la extension mp4 o algun texto video, facilmente encontrarás el video. El link al mismo es: https://p.w3layouts.com/demos_new/30-01-2017/classic_login_form-demo_Free/395814285/web/video/Ipad.mp4

Comment: Eso no esta codificado, simplemente esta minificado (y probablemente ofuscado) para ocupar menos. Usa un editor de JS que permita formatear el codigo y podras leerlo mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anduve mirando tu pregunta y lo que debo decirte es lo siguiente.
Funciona asi...
1º Pones por ejemplo....

```
<script src="js/jquery.vide.min.js"></script>
```

2º Colocas el div por ejemplo...

```
<div data-vide-bg="video/Ipad"></div>
```

3º Listo ya saldria el video.
Ahora la magia que te explico.
En la etiqueta... data-vide-bg="video/Ipad"  ahi colocas lo que seria la url relativa del video... en este caso el que hay en esa web es video/Ipad.mp4 video/Ipad.webm video/Ipad.ogv
ese seria el ejemplo de como queda...

```
https://p.w3layouts.com/demos_new/30-01-2017/classic_login_form-demo_Free/395814285/web/video/Ipad.mp4
```

Asi que si pones ejemplo...

```
<div data-vide-bg="video/Control"></div>
```

el resultado seria Control.mp4
Control.webm Control.ogv
 aunque no es necesario poner los 3 formatos... al igual que la page que vos pasaste...
tambien puedes cambiar la url relativa ejemplo...

```
<div data-vide-bg="ocultados/Control"></div>
```

entonces la url relativa del video seria  `Urltuweb/ocultados/Control.mp4`

```
<div data-vide-bg="ocultados/Control" style="position: relative;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 50%; background-image: none;">
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" style="margin: auto; position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: visible; width: auto; height: 777px;">
<source src="ocultados/Control.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="ocultados/Control.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="ocultados/Control.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado con las etiquetas HTML ya que se pueden usar para dar formato a las respuestas. Revisar la ayuda del editor para que conozcas las opciones de edición e insersión de código.

Comment: Okey la proxima vez miro con mas atencion gracias por la edicion de mi respuesta y hacerla mas entendible y ordenada.